# Push Notifications for ASP.Net MVC PWA

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I am in the process of building a PWA using ASP.NET and would like to add push notifications. The application is a survey app and I have a  SQL database which has a table which stores the user Id, last completed date of survey 1, and last completed date of survey 2. I'd like to add a push notification  for when the last completed date has gone past 7 days to prompt the user to go into the PWA and complete the survey again. Being new to ASP and PWAs, I've tried searching but have so far found no solution on how to go about implementing this, or even if what I'm  trying to do is possible. Hoping theres someone out there that can offer a bit of guidance? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked this blog - [Push notifications to your PWA with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and Aurelia](https://www.bartvanuden.com/2018/01/23/push-notifications-to-your-pwa-with-asp-net-core-2-0-and-aurelia/)?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm (new to ASP.NET and PWAs) in the process of building a PWA using ASP.NET

Why not use Angular (or React), use Firebase Hosting to host your PWA and take advantage of Firebase Cloud Messaging!

Comment: It's for a college project using the traditional  front technologies...just started learning then so not up to scratch with angular or react. It's  too late to remodel